# Returning a Collection with Generic Projections so multiple Projections can be selected in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

I am trying to be able to select from multiple projections as return type in a collection when accessing a method in a jpa repository

I have come across this thread, however its information is not really sufficient:
[Spring Data Jpa generic projection findAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441324/spring-data-jpa-generic-projection-findall)

It seems like i cant use a list, but i dont understand why and its not explained in that thread.

I want to get the following code to work:

```
public interface ThemingRepository extends JpaRepository<ThemeData, Long> {
  <T> List<T> findByOrderByIdAsc(Class<T> type);
}

  @Transactional
  public byte[] findBackgroundImage() {

    var list = themingRepository.findByOrderByIdAsc(ThemeDataBackgroundImage.class);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoThemeColorsSetException();
    }
    return list.get(0).getBackgroundImage();
  }

  @Transactional
  public byte[] findLogoImage() {

    var list = themingRepository.findByOrderByIdAsc(ThemeDataLogoImage.class);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoThemeColorsSetException();
    }
    return list.get(0).getLogo();
  }

  @Transactional
  public ThemeDataColors findThemeColors() {

    var list = themingRepository.findByOrderByIdAsc(ThemeDataColors.class);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoThemeColorsSetException();
    }
    return list.get(0);
  }
```

An example projection:

```
public interface ThemeDataBackgroundImage {
  byte[] getBackgroundImage();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352967/spring-jpa-using-multiple-projection-on-same-query-interface

Same Thing in this Thread

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.